# What exactly is INTERVAL 1 HOUR checking?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, date

MariaDB 10.1.x

Let's say I have a query like:

`select FOO from db.BLAH where STAMPFOO > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR`

If I run that query at 12:15 PM, will I only get records that have a date value greater than 11:15 AM?  Or greater than 11:00 AM?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276110/mysql-select-records-1-hour-ago-or-fresher-on-datetime-column

Comment: Perform `SELECT NOW(), NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;` -- that should make the answer obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `WHERE` clause says [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), the expression `STAMPFOO > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR` makes this a dynamic query. It will return all records whose timestamp is greater than one hour ago, down to the very second.

If you run this at `2017-02-02 12:15:27`, your query will return all FOO values  from `2017-02-02 11:15:27`.